# Remapping WASD + R_Shift to arrows

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I know this has already been asked so many times, but even after searching, I still can't do it.

I simply want to map R_Shift + WASD to the arrow keys (Linux). I can map Shift + WASD to arrows using xmodmap, however, I want only the right shift to have this functionality (while disabling text selection when using R_Shift).

(I have read the xmodmap wiki but can't really understand the way to make this possible.)

Answer (score 2):

After countless minutes of testing, I finally found what I needed.

You need to create an `.Xmodmap` with the following contents:

```
keycode 62 = Mode_switch
keysym a = a A Left
keysym d = d D Right
keysym s = s S Down
keysym w = w W Up
```

`62` is the key code of `R_Shift`.

It works perfectly.